# Nextcloud doesn't allow access, despite address being whitelisted in config.php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, cloud, nextcloud

I installed an UCS Univention App virtual machine with Collabora integrated with Nextcloud. After installation I accessed Nextcloud without any issue, but I did't set a static IP. Next day I came back and Nextcloud refused access, DHCP assigned something else. I ran through updates, set a static IP and added it to the trusted_domains array. I've rebooted several times during the process and the issue is still there.
[image: screenshot of cmd, vm and browser]

Answer (score 0):

I've reinstalled my virtual machine and it works. I've also kept to the old version. I think there might be a problem with certificates or config files, that I've either  edited the wrong config.php file or those certs stuck to the old IP address.